# Use linefeed or carriage return in Subversion commit message from the command line

Tags: linux, svn, bash, command-line-interface

I am using Subversion 1.6.6 on Ubuntu 10.04, running a bash shell. I would like to insert a carriage return, or linefeed, or newline into my commit message so that when reading the log, the comments are formatted appropriately. It works fine when I use the system editor, or specify a file for the commit comment, but what I really want is to be able to do something like the following:

```
svn ci -m "This is the first line\nThis is the second line"
```

and have the comment presented as:

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
```

My example does not work, it produces output:

> This is the first line\nThis is the
>   second line

So, is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
svn ci -m $'This is the first line\nThis is the second line'
```

Comment: That appears to have the same problem, with the subversion log not interpreting the "\n".

Comment: actually, the subversion log worked fine with Dennis' solution.

Comment: Interesting, must be because I'm still running 9.10.  I'm glad the simpler command worked!

Comment: @Paul: This is a shell feature. It should work in Ubuntu 9.10. Are you sure you're trying it with the dollar sign and *single* quotes? As a test, at the shell prompt, enter `echo $'one\ntwo'` it should give you the same output as `echo -e 'one\ntwo'` which should be "one" on one line and "two" on the next. Double quotes would also work for the `echo -e` version.

Answer (score 1):

Just hit enter when you're typing it, instead of the \n.  The prompt will turn to ">" and you can continue typing.

This is a shell question, not a Subversion question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and sorry for the mis classification.

My goal is to put this into a bash script, so if there is any to do this without hitting enter that would help.

Comment: svn ci -m "this is a test --- next line ---
> just a test"

Figures I'd have newline problems in the comment about a newline problem :).  It'll look like that with the ">" on the next line like Andy said.  You can do the same thing in a script file (just tested it with bash).

Comment: Paul - your command di not work for me.
Dennis' command did work.